# Window 10 Hard Drive encryption without BitLocker

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, encryption

I discovered today that if I plug my Windows 10 SSD hard drive (which is protected by a windows password) using a SSD-to-USB adapter to another laptop. That laptop is able to read the entire content of the hard drive. This sounds unsecure, because if my laptop is ever stolen, someone can access the entire hard drive without entering the windows password.

I did some research, it seems like I need to encrypt the hard disk. Would that prevent someone from accessing the hard drive using a SSD-to-USB adapter?

I also found that Windows has BitLocker which could encrypt the hard drive. But I have a windows 10 home edition, and apparently, it doesn't come with BitLocker according to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-on-device-encryption-0c453637-bc88-5f74-5105-741561aae838).

How should I encrypt my hard drive then?

Comment: There are open source encryption solutions that are free, but I haven't used them so I won't recommend a specific one.

Comment: There are only two FDE solutions I would even begin to use.  The first is BitLocker.  The second is VeraCrypt.  Any other solution I would not trust with my data. "Would that prevent someone from accessing the hard drive using a SSD-to-USB adapter?" - Your current solution did not actually encrypt anything on the disk, so of course you can attach it to another computer, and view the contents of that disk.  Full disk encryption (FDE) encrypts the entire disk, this means without the key to decrypt the data, your data is safe.

Comment: I would suggest VeraCrypt, as BitLocker can be problematic for its new users.